# isomorphism of abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, algebraic-groups

Let $A, B, C$ and $D$ be abelian varieties (over $\mathbb{C}$) such that $A \times B \cong C \times D$, and $A \cong C$.  From the irreducibility of abelian varieties, we can say that $B$ and $D$ are isogeneous.  But do we actually have $B \cong D$?

Comment: I think that rather than "irreducibility" you mean "complete reducibility" or "Poincare's complete reducibility theorem".  As for the question itself: I seem to recall that it is famously false for supersingular abelian varieties, i.e., in positive characteristic.  Over C, I might guess that it's true, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I meant the complete reducibility theorem.  Thanks.

Comment: It is false also in characteristic $0$ though there it is true for elliptic curves (see Angelo's reply). It is a question of finding an example of non-cancellation for projective modules over a suitable ring and then mirror it for abelian varieties. See Poonen, "The Grothendieck ring of varieties is not a domain" for an example. (Bjorn's example is somewhat involved as he wants an example over $\mathbb Q$. An example over $\mathbb C$ is easier to construct.)

Comment: @Torsten: I think the example in my paper was of something slightly different, namely A x A = B x B with A and B not isomorphic.

Comment: @Bjorn: You are right of course, I misremembered. (In my defence, an example of non-cancellation also gives examples of zero-divisors in the Grothendieck ring, the  tricky thing is to get an example over $\mathbb Q$.)

Comment: @Bjorn: In the remark (3) in your paper "The Grothendieck ring of varieties is not a domain", you mentioned elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Does that mean that there exist elliptic curves $A\not\cong B$ over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $A\times A \cong B\times B$?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is false even for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$. This was proved by T. Shioda in "Some remarks on abelian varieties"  J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo Sect. IA Math.  24  (1977), no. 1, 11-21, http://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2261/6164/1/jfs240102.pdf.

Comment: This is a very interesting paper.  I look forward to reading it carefully.  